# Webstorm Shortcut to create new file from src

Tags: webstorm

What is the shortcut to create a file when the cursor is on the beginning of the name in the src.

I did it by accident earlier today and can't remember the key combo. Searched all over the web with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Universal shortcut: <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> when having cursor standing on problematic place (or click on light bulb icon) and choose appropriate action from appeared menu:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Never use that key combo for a new file before...but thanks!